# VSCode and Typescript 5 moduleResolution "bundler"

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use typescript 5.0.2 and vscode 1.76.2 with the new moduleResolution "bundler" setting in tsconfig.  I'm building a frontend with vite so typescript is only being used for typechecking with `--noEmit`.  I can individually get vscode and `tsc --noEmit` to work with different tsconfigs, but can't get both to work together.

### Module node16

If in tsconfig.json, I have

```
{
  "module": "node16",
  "moduleResolution": "bundler"
 ...
}
```

then Visual Studio Code works perfectly, it typechecks all files and everthing is great.  But, running `tsc --noEmit` gives the error

```
tsconfig.json:4:25 - error TS5095: Option 'bundler' can only be used when 'module' is set to 'es2015' or later.

4     "moduleResolution": "bundler",
                          ~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error in tsconfig.json:4
```

### Module es2020

From the above tsc error, I try and change tsconfig.json to have

```
{
  "module": "es2020",
  "moduleResolution": "bundler"
 ...
}
```

Now running `tsc --noEmit` works perfectly, it runs and typechecks everything perfect.  But now vscode is broken.  When I open a ts file in vscode, vscode cannot resolve any of the references.  When I mouse over an import like @mui/material, vscode gives the error

```
Cannot find module '@mui/material'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?
```

### Two separate tsconfigs

For now, I just made two separate tsconfigs.  tsconfig.json has "module": "nodenext" so that vscode works and then I point tsc to a separate tsconfig.file.

Is there a configuration of tsconfig which can work with both tsc and vscode?

Comment: Wait... you were just trying an option for fun? That's awesome!

Answer (score 12):

That's really only a VSCode version issue.

I was using the **VSCode 1.76.2** and I had the same issue. I had errors on my *vite.config.js* file, when I imported *vite* and *@vitejs/plugin-react*. Also, I had errors in any other file when I try to import third-party libraries.
In that VSCode version, the only fix I found was to change from `bundler` to `node` both in **tsconfig.json** and **tsconfig.node.json**

The `bundler` module resolution is a new feature, implemented on [Typescript 5.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#moduleresolution-bundler) and I think VSCode wasn't 100% ready for it.

I've just updated here (now I have **VSCode 1.77.3**) and could change back both **tsconfig.json** and **tsconfig.node.json** module resolutions to `bundler`. No more issues!

Comment: I was in v 1.70  and upgraded to v1.8 and the error gone

Answer (score 1):

For others who find this answer and none of the above works, double check your TS version. In one repository I edited, upgrading from 4 -> 5 did the trick.

Before you shout I realize the OP specified they were using TS 5, this answer is here for those of us who are not *detail oriented*.

Comment: Wait, but no one mentioned why you're all trying this new option. Why?

Comment: @NeoZoom.lua I assume you mean why are we using moduleResolution=bundler? If that's your question then the reasons are here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution.
In short: it models how imports would work with a bundler.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error with my co-worker `Cannot find module '@mui/material'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?`

My co-worker was on an older vscode version... 1.73.1 iirc.

I tried to run `Select typescript version` in the command palette, but it wouldn't appear on my co-workers machine.

I verified we had this in the repos `.vscode/settings.json` file:

```
  // Nice to have for any repo:
  // (use `typescript` version that's inside `node_modules`)
  "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib",
  "typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk": true,
```

The hover description for `enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk` is "Enables prompting of users to use the TypeScript version configured in the workspace for Intellisense."

Then we reloaded vscode... patiently waited a little bit... and got this popup in the bottom right of vscode:
[image: Screenshot: This workspace contains a typescript version. Would you like to use the workspace typescript version for typescript and javascript language features? Allow Dismiss Never in this Workspace]

We of course clicked "Allow" and viola, `moduleResolution: 'bundler'` worked fine, all the import statements worked fine, hover annotations, clicking package imports would open the .d.ts files... :)