tslib problems in Angular 18
I am creating a new project in angular 18. When entering the app.component file my text editor (vscode) shows me an error in the @Component decorator."This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found.ts(2354)"

Now the "temporary" solution I found was in the tsconfig.json file to change the moduleResolution property from "bundler" to "node".
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "moduleResolution": "node" //"bundler"
}

Now I don't understand exactly why this happens. I already removed all my extensions from the editor and I can't find any other solution than what I already mentioned.

Angular CLI: 18.0.2
Node.js: 20.14.0


check if tslib is installed "tslib": "^2.3.0", else download this project and check if you still get the error? stackblitz

Does the error not happen on build? Then the problem is very specific to the editor. It's unknown what's the version, it could be that it doesn't support "bundler". Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75870063/vscode-and-typescript-5-moduleresolution-bundler

The extension "ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next" was the one that was causing the problem. Thanks for the help ;)

I found a solution to this problem with Blunder, you just have to comment out or remove the importHelpers line from tsconfig.json and configure it in the compillerOptions of tsconfig.app.json.
tsconfig.json
tsconfig.app.json

Add code in answer.
